# SQL Server 2008 R2 Replication conflict

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-replication

We have software that during the installation or updates it drop and adds all of its views, triggers, and stored procedures. This became a problem when we tried to implement a snap shot replication on two SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard machines. Setting up the repication was fine, but during the update process Replication stopped the update because it wouldn't let go of the stored procedures that it was replicating (sorry, I don't have the error handy, I will try to post it later).

My question is, can replication work in an environment where the various pieces of the database are changing frequently? We sometimes will change our table structure, but only to add columns. Our installer does not drop tables though, it only drops the views, triggers, and SPs.